# NetworkStream.GetStream() returning unexpected result

Tags: c#, networkstream

```
NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
byte[] inStream = new byte[10025];
 serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
 string[] delim = {"!###!"};
 string[] returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream).Split(delim, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

returndata[0] is supposed to be a string of 2 chars "fs".
Using switch() or if() it never match "fs".
"fs" is supposed to be 2 length, when i try returndata[0].length it says 10025...
But when i Debug.WriteLine() its displaying "fs" only..
please help.

edit:
datas received are sent like this:

```
byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("fs!###!somethingsblabalkla");
serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
serverStream.Flush();
```

Comment: \0 values? Is the string padded with nulls to match length?

Comment: edited incase it answers your questions :/ i send strings, dont add anything manually, and matching simply by if (returndata[0] == "fs")

Comment: ah I missed something in your original post : you *want* it to be 10025 length therefor it is 10025 in length

Comment: i would urge you to look into here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839778/c-sharp-network-stream-getstring-method

Comment: Your general approach is doomed to failure because TCP/IP is stream-based, not packet-based. This means you can receive strings that don't contain your delimiter at all because they were split in the middle. Your code will need to be more complicated to handle that -- or you can make your strings line-based and wrap the `NetworkStream` in a `StreamReader`.

Comment: i will look at it thanks. @Leon I still dont understand why after the Split() it is still 10025 tho. as its from string start to delimiter. :/

Comment: To continue on what Jeroen said, go read http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html to understand what "Stream-based. not packet-based" means. And to answer your question it is because you told it that `byte[] inStream` was `10025` long, Calling `Read` does not modify the size of the array you passed in to `GetString`. There is a very important reason `Read` returns a `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Your byte buffer is 10025. That's final, it never changes. The amount of bytes received is in the return value of the `Read` method, which you're completely ignoring. The string you get from `GetString` thus has all the 10025 characters, and only when you print them out are the zeroes ignored.

In any case, this is not proper TCP. It will not work anyway, not reliably. Try to avoid writing your TCP code unless you really know what you're doing - have a look at WCF, HTTP, or Lindgren - it will probably be a lot better idea than doing your own TCP code.

Comment: can anyone tell me if this method is taking care of that "splitted" packets you were all talking about ? http://technotif.com/creating-simple-tcpip-server-client-transfer-data-using-c-vb-net/

Comment: This project looks like perfect for handling splitted stream etc https://nitoasync.codeplex.com

Comment: @user3916429 You need to repeat the read (with offset) for as long as you need to get the whole message. And after that, you need to make sure you store any extra data left in the buffer. The link you've sent isn't atrocious TCP - it will work well for such a simple case. But it only ever reads the whole thing at once, similar to how HTTP works. It will not work if you need to keep the connection alive and send (and read) multiple commands over time - it will keep reading until the client closes the socket. NitoAsync is a great library, but I don't think it helps with TCP, just async sockets.